# Issue with load_img- Error- FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, image

```
for i in os.listdir("D:/Deep Learning/vgg16_images"):
print(i)

image=[]
for i in os.listdir(r'D:\Deep Learning\vgg16_images'):
    img = load_img(i,target_size=(224, 224))
    img=img_to_array(img)
    img = img.reshape((1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]))
    # prepare the image for the VGG model
    img = preprocess_input(img)
    image.append(img)
```

> The for loop at the top throws 4 images 1) bus.jpg 2) mug.jpg 3) schoolbus.jpg 4) traffic.jpg

> the next section of the code at load_img throws the error
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bus.jpg'

**Path and image name extension are all correct, the same code works if i remove the image "bus". and the issue is not with that particular image, if i add any other image it throws the error**

**the pattern i saw was that once i run the code on x number of images and then when i rerun the code by adding new images it throws the error, tried resolving it by restarting the kernel and closing and refreshign the folders aswell**

Comment: Update- Placing the images in same folder as the notebook works `i=[i for i in os.listdir(r'D:\Deep Learning\vgg16_images')]` and replacing the os path in for loop with i             `image=[]
for j in i:
    img = load_img(j,target_size=(224, 224))
    img=img_to_array(img)
    img = img.reshape((1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]))
    # prepare the image for the VGG model
    img = preprocess_input(img)
    image.append(img)`

Answer (score 0):

my apologies..this question should not have been there in the first place, realized it later..those days when the brain stops working completely

The mentioned directory and load_img paths are different. load_imp was working for all images other than the bus.jpg was because those images were there in both the folder paths

Not deleting the question though- someday someone might have the bad day as well